# How does a GiST index really work?

Tags: database, data-structures, gist

I use GiST indexes pretty often, so I understand their performance characteristics and the API that they use and why you'd want one. What I don't understand is, under the covers, how exactly do they work? I'm looking for an explanation of the underlying data structures and algorithms behind it.

If I wanted to implement my own GiST index, how would I do that? Ideally I'd love to see sample code of a super-simple non-optimized version which I couldn't find anywhere on the web, since that would help me understand it best.

Answer (score 3):

> If I wanted to implement my own GiST index, how would I do that?

1. Go to [GiST homepage](http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/)
2. Read the papers
3. Read the [libgist](http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/libgist-2.0/) source code with reference implementation of the Generalized Search Tree
4. Check related [software utilities](http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/software.html) to debug and visualize GiST index
5. Design and develop our own better and improved implementation